# Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function, when trying to integrate external plugins into my Meteor app

Tags: meteor

Trying to integrate a plugin that is not available as a package into my Meteor app.

Here's the code:

```
import $ from "meteor/jquery";
import jQuery from "meteor/jquery"

     (function($, window, document){
       'use strict';

         var doc = $(document);

         window.notifyAlert = function(){

           var $this  = $(this),
               onload = $this.data('onload');

           if(onload !== undefined) {
             setTimeout(function(){
               notifyNow($this);
             }, 800);
           }

           $this.on('click', function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             notifyNow($this);
           });

         }

         function notifyNow($element) {
           var message = $element.data('message'),
               options = $element.data('options');

           if(!message)
             $.error('Notify: No message specified');

           $.notify(message, options || {});
         }


     }(jQuery, window, document));
```

Here's the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

I wrapped the function to be immediately invoked in the context of the jQuery object, since I thought that will surely help solve the problem and prevent interference with the global namespace, but nope, same problem.

If you take take the immediate invocation out, obviously it won't work either. So I'm completely lost at what to do here.

I only have this error when working with Meteor and nowhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Both `$` and `jQuery` are accessible as properties of the package import, so import them using bracket notation:

```
import {$, jQuery} from 'meteor/jquery';
```

Note that depending on your file load order, you may also be able to access it from the window object inside your imported file:

```
const {$} = window;
```